# Fill the missing data by the average or the most frequent string

Tags: r

I am new to R. My dataframe has some missing data. For example:

```
Temperature   Location
  10.2        New York
  13.2        New York
              Toronto
  10
```

I want fill the numeric columns by the average of the column and fill the non-numeric columns by the most frequent string. I this case, it will be "New York
". Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Helpful: `is.na()`, `dplyr::coalesce()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data frame is called `df`:

```
df$Temperature[is.na(df$Temperature)] <-
  mean(df$Temperature, na.rm = T)

df$Location[is.na(df$Location)] <-
  names(sort(table(df$Location), decreasing = T)[1])
```